# Is there a way to detect if telegram bot has been started in private?

Tags: python, telegram, py-telegram-bot-api

This project has been developed on pyTelegramBotAPI module.
what I need to do is to check if the bot has been started in private chat, since that is mainly runned on a group.

If I try to send a message from the group to a player that hasn't started yet the bot, my app crashes:

```
ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful.
                  Error code: 403. Description: Forbidden: bot was blocked by the user"
```

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['inventory'])
def handle_command_adminwindow(message):
    # add column for each 7 elements in matrix
    rootInventory = ref.child("inventory").get()
    userPool = []
    userId = message.from_user.id
    items = []
    for i in rootInventory:
        userPool.append(i)
    userId = f"{userId}"
    if userId in userPool:
        refItems = ref.child("inventory").child(userId).get()
        for i in refItems:
            items.append(i)
        nitem = len(items)
        while(nitem%7!=0):
            nitem += 1
        #load query witj new data
        inventory(message, items)
```

then I declare my call:

```
def inventario(message, items):
    # List object downloaded from firebase and ready for call actions
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    listFruits = ["apple", "banana", "strawberry", "berries", "kiwi", "peach"]
    idGamer = message.from_user.id
    idMsg = message.message_id
    i = 0
    while i < len(items):
        row = []
        if items[i] in listFruits:
            row.append(InlineKeyboardButton(text=items[i], callback_data=f"{idGamer}-cb_f{items[i]}"))
        else:
            row.append(InlineKeyboardButton(text=items[i], callback_data=f"cb_other"))
        i += 1
        if items[i] in listFruits:
            row.append(InlineKeyboardButton(text=items[i], callback_data=f"{idGamer}-cb_f{items[i]}"))
        else:
            row.append(InlineKeyboardButton(text=items[i], callback_data=f"cb_other"))
        i += 1
        markup.row(*row)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "You can now check your inventory in pvt\nlink to pvp chat with bot")
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Inventory', reply_markup=markup)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is chat **type** attribute  to distinguish between **Private Chat** and **Group Chat**

```
if message.chat.type == "private"
    # private chat message
else:
    # non-private chat message
```

Other supported **type** are "channel" , "group", "supergroup"

Comment: Also possible: `from telegram import Chat` and then `message.chat.type == Chat.PRIVATE`